# hibernate adds fraction part of BigDecimal after I hit findAll() 5x

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I found a really strange behaviour of Hibernate (6.2.7), Springboot 3.1.3, PostgreSQL. Reproducible also with Hibernate 5.8 and springboot 2.7. I supposed it has something to do with Hibernate L1 cache. I have data stored like this in DB:

[image]

Then I have JPA entity defined:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@ToString
@Table(name = "lukas_test")
public class TestEntity {

  @Id
  private int id;

  private BigDecimal value;

}
```

and repository:

```
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<TestEntity, Integer> {}
```

now, when I do this from our tests:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  System.out.println(testRepository.findAll());
}
```

I get this result:

```
[TestEntity(id=1, value=0)]
[TestEntity(id=1, value=0)]
[TestEntity(id=1, value=0)]
[TestEntity(id=1, value=0)]
[TestEntity(id=1, value=0)]
[TestEntity(id=1, value=0.0)]
[TestEntity(id=1, value=0.0)]
[TestEntity(id=1, value=0.0)]
[TestEntity(id=1, value=0.0)]
[TestEntity(id=1, value=0.0)]
```

Fractional part is added after I make 5 calls. This is reproducible and always leads to same result.

This works also across tests - we have strict assertions (0 != 0.0), so this is randomly breaking our tests - depends on in which order they are executed.  I have suspicion Hibernate L1 cache is involved into this, but even so, it should not modify underlying data?

Comment: `5` is a magic number in PostgreSQL world, please check for example: [ResultSet.getString() returns inconsistent results with SQL Type double](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/1286)

Comment: at the end, we migrated our JPA entity to BigDecimals, now we consistently receive only "0.0"